# Why camera doesn't follow the user position

Tags: ios, sygic-mobile-sdk

my problem is when I'm in navigation using the Sygic mapView the camera doesn't follow the user position despite that I choose this mode

```
mapView.cameraMovementMode = .followGpsPositionWithAutozoom
```

I didn't know if there is an other setting that I should  follow the user position after starting the navigation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work the way you are using it. Did you try move camera somewhere out of your position and then call `mapView.cameraMovementMode = .followGpsPositionWithAutozoom`? It should set camera to your position and following your gps.

- Are you initializing `SYMapView` after SDK is initialized?
- Do you call `SYPositioning.shared().startUpdatingPosition()` after SDK is initialized? So SDK will start updating your location

You can register your class to `SYPositioningDelegate` and implement `-(void)positioning:(nonnull SYPositioning*)positioning didUpdatePosition:(nonnull SYPosition*)position;` method, so you can print your position.